# Getting length of factors inside a list of data frames [R]

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

Im trying to apply —lapply— a function to create a column with the length of factors in several data frames inside a list.

Here's my example data:

```
> head(m.list)
$df.1
         Date Years
56 1967-01-17  55  
10 1981-07-27  40  
34 1973-09-30  48  
98 1944-03-17  78  
27 1986-07-17  35  

$df.2
         Date Years
56 1967-01-17  55  
10 1981-07-27  40  
34 1973-09-30  48  
98 1944-03-17  78  
27 1986-07-17  35
```

I've manage to create groups using breaks:

```
year_cut <- function(m.list, col)
      {cut(m.list[,col],
       breaks=c(10,20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 100),
       right = FALSE,
       labels = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))}

m.list = lapply(m.list, function(x)
                cbind(x, "Group" = year_cut(m.list = x,
                      col ="Years")))
```

```
>head(m.list)    
$df.1
         Date Years Group
56 1967-01-17  55   E
10 1981-07-27  40   D
34 1973-09-30  48   D
98 1944-03-17  78   F
27 1986-07-17  35   B

$df.2
         Date Years Group
56 1967-01-17  55   E
10 1981-07-27  40   D
34 1973-09-30  48   D
98 1944-03-17  78   F
27 1986-07-17  35   B
```

Now I'm trying to get the length of groups, but I failed to do so.

I' ve tried two different approaches unsuccessfully:

```
cut_summary <- function(m.list, col)
{ summarize(
  group_by(m.list,!!as.name(col)),
  length(col)) }
    
m.list = lapply(m.list, function(x)
cbind(x, "cut_total" = cut_summary(m.list = x,
 col ="Group"))) 
    
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 436, 7
    
cut_summary <- function(m.list, col)
{ group_by(m.list,!!as.name(col)) %>% length(col)}
    
m.list = lapply(m.list, function(x)
cbind(x, "cut_total" = cut_summary(m.list = x,
      col ="Group")))

Error in length(., col) :
2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1
```

Ideally, I should get:

```
>head(m.list)    
$df.1
         Date Years Group Total
56 1967-01-17  55   E      22
10 1981-07-27  40   D      32
34 1973-09-30  48   D      32
98 1944-03-17  78   F      4
27 1986-07-17  35   B      20

$df.2
         Date Years Group Total
56 2005-01-17  17   A      22
10 1981-07-27  40   C      19
34 1973-09-30  48   E      3
98 1944-03-17  78   F      50
27 1986-07-17  35   B      4
```

Any help is most welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may create two columns with `mutate/add_count` - loop over the `list` with `purrr::map` (or `lapply` from base R), then `mutate` to create the 'Group' column by applying the 'year_cut' on the 'Years' column, and use `add_count` to create a count column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(m.list,  ~ .x %>%
               mutate(Group = year_cut(., col ="Years")) %>%
               add_count(Group, name = "Total"))
```

-output

```
$df.1
        Date Years Group Total
1 1967-01-17    55     E     1
2 1981-07-27    40     D     2
3 1973-09-30    48     D     2
4 1944-03-17    78     F     1
5 1986-07-17    35     C     1

$df.2
        Date Years Group Total
1 1967-01-17    55     E     1
2 1981-07-27    40     D     2
3 1973-09-30    48     D     2
4 1944-03-17    78     F     1
5 1986-07-17    35     C     1
```

---

The OP's function applies `length` on a string input.  Instead, it should be `length(!!as.name(col))` or more easily it is `n()`.   Also, `summarise` returns only the grouping columns and the summarised output column.  Based on the expected output, it seems that the OP wants the full dataset or add a new column in the original dataset.  In that case use `mutate`

```
cut_summary <- function(m.list, col)
  { mutate(group_by(m.list,!!as.name(col)), Total = n())}
```

and then calling the already modified `m.list` with

```
m.list <- lapply(m.list, function(x)
                 cbind(x, "Group" = year_cut(m.list = x, col ="Years")))
lapply(m.list, function(x) cut_summary(x, col = "Group"))
$df.1
# A tibble: 5 × 4
# Groups:   Group [4]
  Date       Years Group Total
  <chr>      <int> <fct> <int>
1 1967-01-17    55 E         1
2 1981-07-27    40 D         2
3 1973-09-30    48 D         2
4 1944-03-17    78 F         1
5 1986-07-17    35 C         1

$df.2
# A tibble: 5 × 4
# Groups:   Group [4]
  Date       Years Group Total
  <chr>      <int> <fct> <int>
1 1967-01-17    55 E         1
2 1981-07-27    40 D         2
3 1973-09-30    48 D         2
4 1944-03-17    78 F         1
5 1986-07-17    35 C         1
```

#### data

```
m.list <- list(df.1 = structure(list(Date = c("1967-01-17", "1981-07-27", 
"1973-09-30", "1944-03-17", "1986-07-17"), Years = c(55L, 40L, 
48L, 78L, 35L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("56", "10", 
"34", "98", "27")), df.2 = structure(list(Date = c("1967-01-17", 
"1981-07-27", "1973-09-30", "1944-03-17", "1986-07-17"), Years = c(55L, 
40L, 48L, 78L, 35L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("56", 
"10", "34", "98", "27")))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, very clear code!